# ASP.NET MVC - Como Alterar Atributo "Name" do TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-helper

É possível alterar o name do campo gerado pelo `@Html.TextBoxFor` ? Não achei nada em português relacionado a isso.

Tentei algo como:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ToDate, new { name = "to" })
```

Se eu fizer por exemplo, para o ID ou Style:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ToDate, new { style = "display: none;", id = "to" })
```

Funciona para os dois acima citados, mas não para o nome.

Então existe uma forma de alterar o `name` gerado por default pelo `@Html.TextBoxFor` ?

Comment: Você pode escrever um **Html Helper** para isso mas, se você alterar o nome não vai ser possível postar o formulário, o `MVC` não vai levar o valor do campo para a `Model`, você não quer isso certo? Nesse caso não seria mais fácil declarar um `input` simples no lugar de usar o Helper `Html.TextBoxFor`?

Comment: Mas meu intuito não é usar com o model, mas com parâmetros, separados de um modelo mesmo.

Comment: Então, se não pretende usar o model, por que não usa um elemento `html`então? Ai você pode colocar o nome que quiser. O helper `@Html.TextoBoxFor` é para ser usado pensando em binding e post da model no `MVC`

Comment: Eu uso um model na view, para um formulário, mas também um outro formulário que utiliza um ou outro dado que está preenchido no modelo, mas não todos os dados do modelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse atributo é case sensitive.

Use **Name** invés de *name*:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ToDate, new { Name = "to" })
```

Outro exemplo:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MeuCampo, new { Name = "blabla" })
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Essa não é uma solução porque não vai mudar o name do html e sim vai criar outro atributo com Name, o que é um HTML inválido. Ele pode funcionar apenas pela razão de alguns browsers ignorarem o segundo name e considerarem apenas o primeiro.

Comment: Lendo o texto da pergunta *"É possível alterar o name do campo gerado pelo @Html.TextBoxFor?"* e a outra pergunta *"Então existe uma forma de alterar o name gerado por default pelo @Html.TextBoxFor ?"* entendi que ele precisa mudar o nome do campo. Se não for isso, talvez seria interessante complementar/editar a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Da seguinte forma é possível mudar o name do TextBoxFor

```
       @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ToDate, new
       {
           htmlAttributes = new
           {
               @class = "form-control",
               style = "display:none;",
               id = "to",
               name = "to"
           }
       })
```

Comment: Não é identificado que new { name = "to"} é um htmlAttributes ? Assim como faz para id e style?

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta

Comment: Se eu faço new { id= "to"}, ele identifica que isso é um htmlAttributes. Mas por qual motivo  new { name = "to"}, não o faz ? Pois seu exemplo, seria basicamente repetir isso, só que de forma explícita, certo ?

Comment: Desconheço o porque dessa forma funciona e da outra não, tive o mesmo problema e só dessa forma funcionou.